# Calculate Date +1 without saturday and sunday?

Tags: java, android, date, web

i need to calculate the date for a website.

```
    case R.id.menu_next:
        // Toast message
        Toast.makeText(this, "Morgen",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Calculate Date
        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentDay=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        //Set the date to 1 day
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, currentDay+1);
        // Set URL
        mWebview .loadUrl("http://divers.ommelandercollege.nl/webportalen/dagrooster.php?datum="+cal.getTime());
        setContentView(mWebview );
        break;
```

With this code it will always load the next day, when pressing that button.
But the problem is when it is friday or saturday and you press the button it needs to load monday but it does still load the next day. How do i solve this?

And i need to get the date into 22-6-2013 format without the time, becuase the site needs:
http://divers.ommelandercollege.nl/webportalen/dagrooster.php?datum=21-6-2013
(dd-mm-yyy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increment the date while checking that the day is neither Saturday or Sunday. A `do-while` loop will ensure that the increment occurs *at least once*.

```
do {
   cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
} while (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY || 
                cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY);
```

The answer your second question: How to output the date in this format: `VRIJDAG 21 JUNI 2013`, use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
String outputDate = 
        new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMM yyyy").format(cal.getTime())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do i get the date into this format: http://divers.ommelandercollege.nl/webportalen/dagrooster.php?datum=21-6-2013

Comment: Thank again, but now is the problem if it is december it needs 12 but in juni it needs 6 and not 06

Comment: For that use the `M` `DateFormat` pattern

Answer (score 1):

```
int dayOfWeek=Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
if(dayOfWeek==Calendar.FRIDAY){
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, currentDay+3);
}
else if(dayOfWeek==Calendar.SATURDAY){
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, currentDay+2);
}
else{
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, currentDay+1); 
}
```

Comment: Like your answer, it is pretty simple but almost what i needed